# Sequelize Query Failing

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a model that has same model associated twice. Below is the model definition

```
const RiStockSplitType = sequelize.define("RiStockSplitType",
    // Columns
    base.addColumns({
        "id": {type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true},
        "splitType": {type: DataTypes.INTEGER, defaultValue: 1, field: "split_type"}
    }, DataTypes),
    // Configs
    new base.DefaultModelConfig("table")
);
RiStockSplitType.associate = function (models, value) {
    value.belongsTo(models.ReservationInfo, {
        foreignKey: {
            allowNull: false,
            name:"reservation_info_id"
        },
        as: "reservation_info"
    });
    value.belongsTo(models.ReservationInfo, {
        foreignKey: {
            allowNull: false,
            name:"split_type_ri_id"
        },
        as:"split_type_ri"
    });
};
return RiStockSplitType;
```

Below is the SequelizeQuery that I am firing

```
 RiStockSplitType.findAll({
        include: [{
            model: ReservationInfo,
            as:"reservation_info"
        }],
    })
)}).then(function(){console.log(arguments)}).catch(err => {console.error('ERROR:', err);});
```

The SQL Query generated by the above is

```
Executing (default): SELECT `RiStockSplitType`.`id`, `RiStockSplitType`.`split_type` AS `splitType`, `RiStockSplitType`.`created_on` AS `createdOn`, `RiStockSplitType`.`updated_on` AS `updatedOn`, `RiStockSplitType`.`reservation_info_id`, `RiStockSplitType`.`split_type_ri_id`, `reservation_info`.`id` AS `reservation_info.id`, `reservation_info`.`created_on` AS `reservation_info.createdOn`, `reservation_info`.`updated_on` AS `reservation_info.updatedOn`, `reservation_info`.`city_id` AS `reservation_info.city_id` FROM `warehouse_ristocksplittype` AS `RiStockSplitType` LEFT OUTER JOIN `warehouse_reservation_info` AS `reservation_info` ON `RiStockSplitType`.`reservation_info_id` = `reservation_info`.`id`;
```

And the error I get is

```
  SequelizeDatabaseError: Unknown column 'reservation_info.city_id' in 'field list'
```

I am using Sequelize v4 and Node 6.9.5.
I am unable to figure out the reason for the error. The column mentioned in the error is `reservation_info.city_id` is there in the Database

**EDIT**

Model definiton for ReservationInfo

```
const ReservationInfo = sequelize.define("ReservationInfo",
    // Columns
    base.addColumns({
        "id": {type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true},
    }, DataTypes),
    // Configs,
    new base.DefaultModelConfig("warehouse_reservationinfo"));

ReservationInfo.associate = function (models, value) {
    value.belongsTo(models.City, {
        foreignKey: {
            allowNull: false,
            name: 'city_id'
        }
    });
};
return ReservationInfo;
```

Comment: did you try to execute the SQL Query through the CLI?

Comment: @YochaiAkoka Yes I did and I get the same error.

Comment: Can you post the model definition for ReservationInfo?

Comment: @Faz edited the question.

Comment: Looking at that initially, it seems that the query is joining on warehouse_reservation_info whereas the name passed to DefaultModelConfig is warehouse_reservationinfo. Could there be some mismatch caused here?

Comment: @Faz that was the problem and apparently I had two tables in my db `warehouse_reservation_info` and `warehouse_reservationinfo`. The latter one was the correct one. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query is joining on warehouse_reservation_info whereas the name passed to DefaultModelConfig is warehouse_reservationinfo. There is a mismatch between table names.